# Breusch-Godfrey test in the presence of heteroscedastic residuals

Tags: regression, time-series, least-squares, autocorrelation, heteroscedasticity

*Wooldridge (2013)*  says that the ***Breusch-Godfrey test*** *"requires the homoscedasticity assumption"*.

I tested for heteroscedasticity in my model by applying the ***Breusch-Pagan test***. The test indicates that my residuals are not homoscedastic. As a next step I am trying to decide wether the residuals are autocorrelated or not. I applied the  ***Breusch-Godfrey test***, which indicates that the residuals are autocorrelated.

Is the result of the ***Breusch-Godfrey test*** valid in this case? If not - how do I test for autocorrelation in the presence of heteroscedasticity?